# attribute directive on input, how subscribe to valueChange

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I use **FormReactiveModule**
With **FormBuilder** I create my Form like:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
      street: [null],
      ...
    });
```

And my template is :

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <input formControlName="street" myAttributeDirective/>
</form>
```

If I add an Attribute Directive to my input (here `myAttributeDirective`) how can I subscribe to his input value change like I was doing : `this.form.controls.street.valueChanges.subscribe(...)` ?

Answer (score 2):

> You can make the directive to have an input

```
@Input() set control(control) {
    if(!control || !control.valueChanges) {
       return;
    }
    control.valueChanges.subscribe(...)
}
```

> And you will have the html like this

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <input formControlName="street" myAttributeDirective [control]="form?.controls?.street"/>
</form>
```